# EDIT: iam still need the help : how can i add an secret object into a git secrets and make my app read it once i deploy the yaml file?

Tags: github, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-secrets, git-secret

can someone help me? I have a repository having some YAML files like deployment_app.yaml, and a secret object.
the pod inside the deployment_file must read the secret object during the deployment process and I wanna save the secret object into a git secret but I also still want to let the deployment file be able to read the secret object once the deployment, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done, from the documentation of `git secret`. Read the docs [here](https://git-secret.io/#:%7E:text=Using%20git%2Dsecret%20for%20Continuous%20Integration%20/%20Continuous%20Deployment%20(CI/CD)).

Basically you will have to create a new key-pair in your CI that will be used to decrypt the Git secret during deployment.

Comment: cant i done it from the website directly ?

Comment: No. Your secret is an encrypted file inside your repository. When the repository is cloned in the CI, the CI has no idea how to decrypt the secret you've added using the `git-secret` bash tool on your laptop.

Comment: i meant that i can add the secret file from github website to the repo directly ? like from settings > secrets ?

Comment: No, those tokens are to establish communication between your development machine and your GitHub profile, they are not related to your deployments.

Comment: ok i will try and back to u, tnx ^^

Comment: its changing the extension of the yaml file with .secret and i cant deploy it, any good way ?